# Fast in-memory graph database

Tags: c#, graph-databases

Does anyone know of a good solution out there that can deal with processing a graph of interconnected nodes? For our purpose the nodes are locations and we move material with various attributes between these locations. At some point a user may need to query what material is at a particular location, where it came from etc. What I need to do is walk the graph/tree and sum up quantities along the way depending on what a user requests.

I was thinking an in-memory graph database or alternatively a graph library may be suitable for this kind of problem but I am not 100% sure. It needs to be called from c# 4.5.

I read about Microsoft's [Trinity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trinity/) and there is also [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) but I haven had any experience with any of them.

Comment: These sorts of question are [off-topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Fair point, bit I did see a very similar but very old question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816055/graph-database-for-net

Comment: Possibly **primarily opinion-based** because _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"_ [Tell me more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two in-memory c# alternatives:

Fallen-8 - http://www.fallen-8.com/

OrigoDB - https://origodb.com/ The author just mentioned in a mailing list that he was working on a graph example.

We're using VelocityGraph for our graph needs - http://www.velocitygraph.com/

But VelocityGraph  not an in-memory solution, so I'm not sure how it suits your requirements.

Comment: Here's the graph example using OrigoDB: https://gist.github.com/rofr/d5fe5f553327dc00a26a

Answer (score 0):

[Memgraph](https://memgraph.com/) is an in-memory graph database, and it has [support for C#](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/c-sharp).